# C++ compile order

Tags: c++

[Actor.h]

```
#include "../PathEngine/Actor.h"
namespace FightEngine
{
    class Actor
        :public PathEngine::Actor
    {
    private:
        .....
    public:
        Actor();
        ~Actor();
        void SetPosition(int x, int y);
    };
}
```

[Actor.cpp]

```
#include "Actor.h"
namespace FightEngine
{
    Actor::Actor()
        :PathEngine::Actor()
    {
        do something
    }
    Actor::~Actor()
    {

    }
    void Actor::SetPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        do something
    }
}
```

[main.cpp]

```
FightEngine::Actor* actor = new FightEngine::Actor();
actor->SetPosition(400,200);
```

it's give me some

>

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol....

I guess that Actor::SetPosition(x,y), Actor::Actor(), declared but aren't defined. BUT I ACTUALLY DEFINED IT in Actor.cpp. the problem is compiler don't compile Actor.cpp, i don't know why.